# Socket failed when more than 100 players online

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets

I'm using [this](http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism/Csharp) class to connect with a GTA:SA:MP server. My website is showing the online players in a table, but if the playercount is more than 100, it won't respond correctly and will return 0. I tried resizing the `byte[] rBuffer` from 500 to 3402 but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

UDP datagrams have a maximum size on the internet. This will be around 500 bytes. If you need to send more data, you need to partition it, and send it as multiple datagrams. If the API doesn't support this, you should notify the guys who maintain it.

Removing the blank try-catch statements will show the errors more clearly - it's usually a very bad idea to ignore exceptions like this.

Comment: I know what the exception is, because I tested it with a breakpoint.. It's "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Comment: @Aradmey *Connection* failed? On UDP? That's weird. Where exactly is this exception being thrown?

Comment: In `Query.Receive()` - `qSocket.ReceiveFrom(rBuffer, ref endpoint);`

Comment: UDP is 64K packets size limitation. IP if going to do end to end fragmentation and reassembly but this is unnoticed by the sender and receiver. Therefore if the sender sends 64K the receiver will receive 64K if nothing goes wrong on the network. This answer is totally wrong. At least for the  first part.

Comment: @Aradmey Right, so you send a command and then you synchronously wait for a response. That never comes (because the server wasn't able to send such a big datagram or it was lost on the way, most likely), so the `ReceiveFrom` call times out. UDP is not a reliable protocol, and it doesn't handle fragmentation automatically, so this shouldn't really be surprising :)

Comment: @PhilipStuyck You're ignoring routers - that's why I said "on the internet". 64k or thereabouts would often be fine on LAN, but most routers have MTUs around 1500, and retransmits of only ~500. The data was sent from the server, but it never reached the client for reassembly.

Comment: on an ethernet LAN the mtu is also 1500. As I said IP is going to do fragmentation.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Just give it a try. Many routers never even give it a chance of getting fragmented, and of course losing any part of the fragmented datagram causes the same exception.

Comment: @Aradmey Well, you can use TCP (with its own pitfalls), or just send smaller datagrams instead of trying to send everything in one. Ideally, use a well estabilished networking library like Lindgren, for example.

Comment: I tried something like `qSocket.ReceiveFrom(rBuffer, 100, SocketType.Partial, ref endpoint);` but it didn't work either..

Comment: Increase your receive buffer to a way higher value. 32K or something like that. You are dropping part of what you receive yourself. And do that in all locations where you have a rbuffer, and use the same size everywhere. If you have 100 user then you only have a few bytes per user available.

Comment: If I define the size as 32,000, it says it's out of range of valid values. `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: size`

Comment: byte[] rBuffer = new byte[32000]; is not a problem for me, where are you getting this error ?

Comment: found this remark somewhere to prove my case : Provided the buffer is large enough, the standard Berkeley sockets recv() and recvfrom() functions will never return a partial datagram.

Comment: How do I receive partial datagrams then? If it's too large to receive from the server.

Comment: You cannot receive partial datagrams, what you send you will receive or not receive at all. UDP is a packet protocol, TCP is streaming, only then you have to take care of those things, but UDP is a lot simpler. Please let me know what happens with bigger receive buffers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71190/discussion-between-aradmey-and-philip-stuyck).

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Not entirely true - the `ReceiveFrom` will fill the buffer with as much data as it can. But only at the point where it already has the whole datagram assembled, and with no way to get the rest of the data. In any case, that would cause a different exception - the "connection attempt failed" (WSAETIMEDOUT) is basically saying some parts arrived in time and some didn't - it this happens regularly, it basically means you should either handle the fragmentation manually, or use TCP. The automatic UDP fragmentation doesn't really work well over the internet, it's there for LAN.

Comment: TCP is not going to help in that case. TCP has a 50ms timer where he is not going to put something on the wire because he tries to fill up to the mtu. (nagle algorithm). The rule is bypassed if TCP has to ack a received packet,in that case TCP will send what it has already. But here In this particular case TCP would not help.I am used to berkeley sockets, I have to lookup the windows behavior

Comment: the error meaning is Connection timed out.
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed because the connected host has failed to respond. This should only be used in case of a real connect. ie not reacting to TCP SYN. It puzzles me that this error is happening in this scenario. Makes no sense at all.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Well, it's about getting a list of players on a server. That's commonly done using web services, and there's little reason to care about that level of latency. After all, that's why it's there - the idea being that it will help more than it hurts. And you can always `Flush` if you really want to. I'm not saying you should use TCP for the game itself, but for monitoring? Why not?

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Many of the old error messages are cryptic, Winsockets and GDI being quite infamous for that. The error message is paired with error code WSAETIMEDOUT, which fits the UDP scenario a lot better - and it *does* happen when the entire fragmented UDP datagram couldn't be assembled in time. The guys who made the error message just assumed that it would mostly happen on TCP streams rather than UDP.

Comment: Actually there is only one way the know 100% what is going on, watch what is on the wire. OP do you have wireshark ?

Answer (score 1):

UDP basically says if data gets lost it is fine, as receiving it later would make little scene as data is deprecated. Now about the data packet size:

> The length field of the UDP header allows up to 65535 bytes of data.
>   However, if you are sending your UDP packet across an Ethernet
>   network, the Ethernet MTU is 1500 bytes, limiting the maximum datagram
>   size. Also, some routers will attempt to fragment large UDP packets
>   into 512 byte chunks.

Comment: IP which is right below UDP supports fragmentation and reassembly. IP is already going to fragment the packet considering the Mtu of the layer beneeth itself when sending, and when receiving it is going to reassemble the packet to the original state. Hence peer to peer the packet is not touched. If you send a packet of 5K you are going to receive 5K on the receiver or not receive it at all, because IP is best effort.

Comment: @PhilipStuyck Yes, which is exactly what the OP is seeing - he's not getting the data. Parts of the fragmented datagram arrive fine (or with an error message), but the whole datagram is never reassembled. It never gets even close to the application level.

Answer (score 0):

The receive buffers are way to small. Increase there size and you will be fine.

byte[] rBuffer = new byte[500]; -> change 500 to 32000

byte[] rBuffer = new byte[3402]; -> change 3402 to 32000

Where did you get these values from ? If you receive a bigger packet chance is very high you won't get it from your own socket layer. As depicted by Stevens. Berkeley sockets behavior only provide complete packets to the user.

Also change your exception handling to catch the exception rather than ignoring it :

```
catch(Exception Ex)
{
     Trace.Writeline(Ex.Message);
     return false;
}
```

and do that at all locations in the code where there is exceptionhandling.